# Mongo 4.2 query base on date

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to query Mongo using the FIND function, I can't use the aggregate function.

My documents are like this:

```
{
  "name": "Tom",
  "priDate":2010-04-11T00:00:00.000Z
}
```

The query I would like to make is:

Find all documents where ("priDate" + 1 year) is lte today.

Is it possible to do this without using an aggregation query? I can't use the field value in find ..

The query that I would need, I think, would be like this one I made:

```
db.system.profile.find({ 
 "priDate" : 
    {     
        $gte:   new Date(ITSELF + 1 year??) ,     
        $lt :  new Date() 
   } 
})
```

Can you help me?

many thanks, i'm going crazy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see if this works:

```
db.collection.find(
    {
        $expr: {
            $lte: ['$priDate', { $subtract: ['$$NOW', 31536000000] }]
        }
    }
)
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/QJ3BbHTQlgh

Comment: When i try to count results with this query mongo say:
"Mongo Server error (MongoCommandException): Command failed with error 51144 (Location51144): 'Builtin variable '$$NOW' is not available' on server localhost:27017. ".

Whay can i do?

Comment: @SteveAged instead of `'$$NOW'` you can use `new ISODate()`

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB stores dates as milliseconds since epoch, so you can advance a date one year by adding the number of milliseconds in a year using `$add` inside `$expr`, then test with `$lte`:

```
db.system.profile.find({$expr:{$lte:[{$add:["$priDate",31536000000]},new ISODate()]}})
```

Note that this will be off by a day around leap year unless you adjust the number of milliseconds for that.

You expressed the constraint that you cannot use aggregate, but with $expr in Mongo 3.6 onwards, you can use any and all aggregation operators in a find query as well.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/#definition

Comment: Hi, and thanks in the meantime.
Using the query you entered i get results from 2007, something is wrong...
Launching the query now I expect to find the data where the "priDate" is of at most a year ago ...

Comment: Your question asked for `Find all documents where ("priDate" + 1 year) is lte today.` which is all "priDate" except those in the last year.  Switch `$lte` in the query to `$gte` to reverse the meaning.

Comment: I launched this query:

{"$and":[{"priDate":{"$ne":null}},{"$expr":{"$gte":[{"$add":["$priDate",31536000000]},1584096377227]}}]}

And i get results from year 2000... what can i do wrong?

Comment: 1584096377227 is not a date, and data type matters to sort order.  See [comparison sort order](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/index.html#comparison-sort-order)

Answer (score 0):

Adding "1 year" can be be difficult because of leap years or daylight-saving-times.
I suggest [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/), then solution would be

```
db.system.profile.find(
   {
      priDate: {
         $gte: moment().add(1, "year").toDate(),
         $lt: moment().toDate()
      }
   }
)
```

However `priDate >= "today + 1 year" AND priDate < "today"` is not possible. Change the condition according to your needs.